# Fast random number generation - multiple times per ms

Tags: c#, random, milliseconds

I noticed, when using [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), that if `Next()` is called more than one time in a millisecond, it returns the same number (if it has the same parameters). I assume the random algorithm somehow concerns the system's time, and is dependent on that.

I'd like to call `Next()` many times within a single millsecond - is there a way to do this, hopefully with the same Random class? If not, I'd appreciate any resources/other methods of solving this.

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing `new Random().Next()` every time?

Comment: _the random algorithm somehow concerns the system's time_ - No, it doesn't. But creating new Random instances in quick succession produces what you describe. It's not `Next()` but the default constructor.

Comment: There's a lot of useful information about `Random` here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: I agree with @OliCharlesworth, you're doing it wrong. There's no way a pseudo-random number generator used properly would have the problem you're describing. Show us some code.

Comment: Read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx

Answer (score 6):

This is because when you initialise a new instance of `Random` it uses the system clock for the seed. If you do this twice, close enough together, you'll end up using the same seed and so you'll get the same sequence of random numbers from the two instances.

The solution as alluded to in comments already, is to instantiate one `Random` object and then repeatedly call Next() on it, you'll get a new random number every time.

```
var val1 = new Random().Next();
var val2 = new Random().Next(); // quite likely val1 and val2 will be the same

var rnd = new Random();
var val3 = rnd.Next();
var val4 = rnd.Next(); // very unlikely val3 and val4 will be the same
```

Comment: Even if you don't do it fast enough to get the same values back, you'll destroy the randomness of the generator since the seeds are definitely non-random.